# Where does "ta!" come from?

Tags: expressions, history, linguistics

Where does the expression "ta" come from?

Wikipedia has only [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta) to say:

> "ta!", slang, Exclam. Thank you! {Informal}, an expression of gratitude

but no additional information or links about its genesis.

I have only ever heard it from englishmen and -women. Is it used anywhere else in the world? How did it come about? What is its history?

Comment: I have heard it used many times in Autralia. I also use it frequently. On occasion, I have received blank stares from non native-english speakers when I use it.

Comment: I always thought "Ta" and "Ta ta" meant good-bye.

Comment: It may be possible that "ta", a commonly used way of saying thank you derives from the Scots Gaelic, tapadh leibh (TAH-puh LEH-eev), for thank you.

Comment: Do you have a source for this possibly?

Comment: It's also used by some Australians, confusing other Australians who don't use it. Unfortunately, I don't have any more detailed data on use-by-region than that.

Comment: South Africans use it too. I always thought it was the acronym for thanks alot (which we all know should be 'a lot').

Comment: As a 55 year old American that lived in London from 1989-1990, I'd never heard "ta" used until recently (2021-2023). I've heard it used now in New Zealand, England and Australia, mostly by younger twenty-somethings. By context, I can accept that it means "thanks". However, I have heard "ta-ta" used throughout my life (in America too) to mean "goodbye", as in "Ta-ta for now!"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Online Etymology Dictionary says:

> **ta**:   1772, "natural infantile sound
>   of gratitude" [Weekley].

Although possibly originating from the imitative of baby talk, this is in widespread use in the North of England and Wales as an informal "thanks" amongst adults.

American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language says:

> **ta**: *Chiefly British*
>   Used to express thanks.
>   ETYMOLOGY:
>   Baby-talk alteration of "thank you".

Comment: Small children in England are sometimes reminded by their elders to say "tata". I've never heard adults using the double version.

Comment: I've only ever heard 'tata' used as a substitute for goodbye - never as thanks (or ta).

Comment: Obviously written by a southerner. Ta is the normal form of thanks in Northern England

Comment: Ta is also pretty standard in Wales

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't "buy" this etymology at all. "Ta ta" also gets written off as baby talk. If you spend a few weeks in the north of England, you'd quickly realize that "ta" has nothing to do with babies.

Answer (score 17):

My compact version of *The Oxford English Dictionary* lists it as "An infantile word expressing thanks," and dates its first reference from 1772, unless my eyes deceive me (I am momentarily unable to locate the magnifying glass that came with the tome).

Edit:

Thank god for Eric Partridge. He quotes the same *OED* reference, only in larger type. Here is the entry:

> **Ta!**; rarely **taa!**  Thanks!: coll., orig. and mainly nursery: 1772,
>   Mrs Delany, 'You would not say "ta" to
>   me for my congratulation,' O.E.D. Ex a
>   young child's difficulty with *th* and
>   *nks*.

Comment: "I am momentarily unable to locate the magnifying glass that came with the tome" +1 funny.

Answer (score 10):

When a term originates in northern English dialects as "ta" appears to, I often begin by looking at nordic languages as much of northern England was conquered by the Vikings and the parts of the language endure both in words and in the overall sound - if you listen the geordie accent has a definite scandinavian cadence to it.

Looking at modern Danish and Norwegian we see that "Thanks" translates as "Tak" or "Takk" respectively, so it seems to me quite plausible that this provides an origin for "Ta".

Comment: This is a famous *false* etymology of "Ta" (AFAIK).

Comment: Proven by whom?

Comment: The burden of proof is on the one claiming an explanation to be true. :-) The fact that etymological dictionaries don't list this Viking hypothesis is enough, for now.

Comment: Right! I shall use my considerable knowledge of norse languages ( specifically none ) and the considerable libraries at my disposal ( specifically I think there is one somewhere in town, but it only has a few paperbacks ) to prove it directly!

Comment: +1. Very probable explanation. For the words of the baby/kid talk dictionary are very old. The only older group of names are probably the names of the rivers

Comment: @ShreevatsaR;@glenatron The phrase: "it seems to me quite plausible that this ..." doesn't need any proof.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR doesn't a burden of proof also rest on the person claiming that this is a) a famous and b) a *false* etymology? If it's famously false it should be easy to find a source corroborating? 
As an aside, it's not reasonable to contradict someone then demand they provide proof while not providing any proof of your opposing position, unless there's a strong reason to think that one position is more authoritative than the other (and I don't think either is here).

Comment: @frankster Both OED and Douglas Harper's Online Etymology Dictionary (based on Weekley) give the same etymology dating to the 1770s, and nothing about Vikings. I consider them more authoritative than folk etymologies. (Also, one would imagine that if a word really dated to the Viking conquest, then there would be some trace in English earlier than the late 18th century.) I must say I'm no longer sure why ten years ago I thought this was "famous".

Comment: @ShreevatsaR when you talk about an early trace in English, it is important to be aware of who was doing the recording - the northern working class were not traditionally a highly literate demographic and the further back we go the more formal, and less colloquial, writing tends to be. The etymology dictionaries are all that we can currently prove, but it is unusual and lucky to get much in the written record regarding regional spoken language.

Answer (score 6):

I would have said it was just a shortening of "thanks". It was in common use in the days of my youth in Northern England.

It's also used as an abbreviation for "thanks" in internet chat rooms.

Comment: North of England, chatrooms, and Scrabble players (for whom 2-letter words are valuaable).

Answer (score 5):

As an Australian I can say 'ta' is used extensively in Australia.  I can't comment on other explanatios as I am not a language expert. However I would like to suggest, as that many caucasian Australians are of Celtic ancestry, that the possible origin of this word is from the Irish galic word for 'yes' (tá). If you think of 'yes' in a broader context; and as and an affirmative response (i.e. Yes) to an action, it kinda makes sense. Just my thoughts, any comments on this welcome.

Comment: *Tá* does not mean *yes*. It means *is*. The Celtic languages do not have distinct words for *yes* and *no*. Instead, one replies with the verb; in that context (after a question beginning *an bhfuil*), *tá* can mean *yes*.