# "Ta" and "ta-ta"

Tags: etymology, language-evolution

If "ta" means "thank-you", how did "ta-ta" come to  mean "goodbye?" Isn't it basically repeating "ta?", in which case, wouldn't it mean "thanks, thanks!"?

Is there a reason why? Does it lie in their etymologies?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where does "ta!" come from?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5567/where-does-ta-come-from)

Comment: In the US (perhaps elsewhere) "**ta-tas**" is a slang term for breasts - "_Check out the bodacious ta-tas on that girl!_"  It's not very likely to lead to confusion with "ta ta" for "goodbye" - unless you're dealing with a teenager, in which case "ta ta!" is likely to set off a fit of giggling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[tata](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tata)

> also ta-ta, "good-bye," 1823, a word first recorded as infant's speech. Abbreviation T.T.F.N., "ta-ta for now," popularized 1941 by BBC radio program "ITMA," where it was the characteristic parting of the cockney cleaning woman character Mrs. Mopp, voiced by Dorothy Summers.

[ta](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ta)

> 1772, "natural infantile sound of gratitude" [Weekley].

At least that's what Etymology Online states.

Comment: @Alenanno: Wooo, bragging party! Oh, no, it's just comment pollution. Simply had to join in.